# Powerful calculator tool for windows?

Tags: math, language-agnostic

I do a lot of heavy math programming. Often there is a need to check some calculations "by hand", specifically while debugging. Do have good experience with some calculator tool (preferably not with gui buttons like windows calc). It could even be a programming language I guess, such as matlab. I like matlab, but I'm looking for something more lightweight here. Any ideas?

Comment: Excel either from MS or OpenOffice?

Comment: @Ventus: Excel is the MS one, the OOo one is called Calc.

Comment: @nico: I know, but everybody knows what I had in mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like jumping into Python whenever I want to run some quick math calculations, and there are nice numeric libraries for the language if you have complex work to type through. Consider what you need.

If you use the latest version of Python (3.1), you may want to use this [updated tutorial](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/introduction.html#using-python-as-a-calculator) for Python's math.

Comment: Awesome, such a good idea. I did not know there was such a command line client without the need to write long scripts. I will start use python. Then I can do simple string processing testing there as well.

Answer (score 3):

GNU's `bc` is a really advanced arbitrary-precision calculator, using a line-by-line "shell" interface which makes my work quite quick. It's written for Linux-based OSes but there's a Windows port:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bc.htm

Answer (score 1):

Python's got a decent [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) library, so you could use a Python shell - there's always [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) if you need more specialised things too.

There's even a section of the documentation on [Using Python as a Calculator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#using-python-as-a-calculator).

Answer (score 1):

I a agree with the previous answers: *bc* and *python* are great command-line calculators. I use *bc* as Windows calculator replacement most of the time. When it comes to more serious math i use

**R**

R (http://www.r-project.org) has also a command line interface and is especially handy if your math includes statistics and if you need to plot data.